# Repeat observable unless interrupted

Tags: rx-java

How can I create an `Observable` that will be repeated `n` times unless some condition satisfied and then it should be interrupted?

Looking something like `repeatUnless` or similar operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options:

1) If you want to interrupt the value sequence:

```
source.repeat(n).takeWhile(condition);
source.repeat(n).takeUntil(condition);
```

2) If you want to repeat n times or until a condition is no longer satisfied:

```
source.repeatWhen(o -> o.scan(1, (a, b) -> a + 1).takeUntil(i -> i < n || condition)))
```

Comment: How should I handle errors in this flow? For example `source` throws and exception?

Comment: for the second example use .takeWhile instead of .takeUntil because .takeUntil(i -> i < n) will terminate after one increment